# Angular2 in sails application configuration

Tags: angular

I am trying to correctly create an angular2 application within a sails application.

I want the AngularApp to run under /management url

What I have done:

1. Create an ManagementController.js:

```js
module.exports = {
    index: function (req, res) {
        res.locals.layout = 'layouts/angular';
        return res.view('angular/angular-start.ejs');
    }
};
```

2. Created an angular layout under views/layouts/angular.ejs:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Reloyalty Administration Dashboard</title>

    <!-- Viewport mobile tag for sensible mobile support -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
    <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico">

    <!-- Common Scripts-->
    <script src="/common/js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

    <!--SCRIPTS-->
    <!--SCRIPTS END-->

    <script>
        // SystemJS
        // config goes here 
    </script>

    <!-- end AngularJS 2-->
</head>

<body>

<%- body %>


</body>
</html>
```

3. Created a view under views/angular/angular-start.ejs

   Loading...
4. Created a folder **assets/management** where my angular app will be
5. Created the assets/management/**app** folder
6. Added to copy.js:

   grunt.config.set('copy', {
           dev: {
               files: [{
                   expand: true,
                   cwd: './assets',
                   src: ['**/*',
                       '!***/.coffee',
                       '!**/*.ts',
                       '!***/.less'
                   ],
                   dest: '.tmp/public'
               }]
           },
           build: {
               files: [{
                   expand: true,
                   cwd: '.tmp/public',
                   src: ['**/*'],
                   dest: 'www'
               }]
           },
           angular_node_deps: {
               files: [{
                   expand: true,
                   cwd:'.',
                   src: [
                       './node_modules/es6-shim/es6-shim.min.js',
                       './node_modules/systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.js',
                       './node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js',
                       './node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js',
                       './node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js',
                       './node_modules/rxjs/***/.js',
                       './node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
                       './node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
                       './node_modules/@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
                       './node_modules/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
                       './node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js'
                   ],
                   dest: '.tmp/public/js'
               }]
           }
       });

What do I do now to have a it running correctly ... I have been trying all day to make this work so i prefer not to post my code right now but just follow your instructions, since I have made so many changes in my code that I do not understand it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure about what you're doing but I recently succeeded in embedding a simple Angular app into an existing app.

What I've done was simply generating a new project using AngularCLI and then embedding the bundled *.js files (the ones generated by the [ng build](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/build) command) and the root html template inside the existing app, and it worked out of the box.